# Cross Domain Request error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, logstash

I'm trying to do a Cross Domain Request, but I'm getting this error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:31312/. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8887' is therefore not allowed access.

This is my code:

```
  var params = 'a=a';
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest();      
  uri = 'http://127.0.0.1:31312/';
  http.open('POST',uri,true);
  http.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  http.withCredentials = false;
  http.onload = function() { 
    if (http.status == 200) {
      ...
    } else {
      ...
    }
  }
  http.send(params);
```

On the server side, I'm using the [HTTP](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/2.4/plugins-inputs-http.html) plugin from logstash 2.4

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you using nodejs, php or what on the server side? This is a server side issue.

Comment: Got it, the server side is the http input plugin from logstash

Comment: Is this Elasticsearch?

Comment: No elasticsearch is other thing. Logstash is only the logger data. Elasticsearch can be an output to the logs from logstash, but no need.

Comment: You have to add the response header `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"` in the logstash config, you're setting it in the client side, which has no effect whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header needs to be sent by the server in it's response, not by the client in it's request.

I'm not familiar with the logstash plugin, but from a quick look at the docs  that you linked, it looks like you should be able to add it to the response_headers hash in the plugin.